# Encode sorted array to bst

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am converting array to binary search tree using this approach I get root node which contains all the information about tree.
But I want it in format

- The left child of the node at index i is at index 2i + 1
- the right child is at index 2i + 2
- The parent of a node at index i is at
  index [i−1]/2

Basically **output** [16, 10, 24, 7, 12, 20, 28, 4, 8, 11].

as this output satisfies

- parent node i =0 16
- left  2*0+1 = 1 (10)
- and right 2*0+2 = 24
  so 16>10 && 16<24

so bst property is satisfied. hence true and similarly for other array element

.

```
/**/
  function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
      this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
      this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
      this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
  }

var sortedArrayToBST = function(nums) {
    return createBinary(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
}

function createBinary(nums, start, end) {
    if (start > end) {
        return null;
    }
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    const root = new TreeNode(nums[mid]);
    root.left = createBinary(nums, start, mid - 1);
    root.right = createBinary(nums, mid + 1, end);
    return root;
}

nums = [4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];
const root = sortedArrayToBST(nums);
console.log(root);
```

Comment: What is the issue with the approach you've added then?

Comment: it gives the answer in tree ROOT node not in array @AbhinavMathur

Comment: @art which traversal of the BST do you need? Level order, pre-order, in-order or post-order?  For `[16, 10, 24, 7, 12, 20, 28, 4, 8, 11]`, the sorted array is `[4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28]` which doesn't make `16` as the root apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your desired output, it looks like you want to build a [*complete* binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees), which is just one of the possible shapes a binary search tree could have for the given values. This shape does not necessarily put the "middle" value at the root, so that is not a logic you can apply here.

You can instead use a recursive approach that does *not* first determine the root, but will only do that when the left subtree has been generated. So you could say, instead of doing a *pre*order traversal, do an *inorder* traversal. Also, you don't really need to create the node structure, but can immediately populate the target array.

```js
function createBinaryTree(nums) {
    // If your input is already sorted, you can skip this sort call:
    nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const it = nums.values(); // Iterator over nums
    const tree = []; // Result array
    
    function inorderAssign(j) {
        if (j >= nums.length) return; // There is no child here.
        inorderAssign(j*2 + 1); // Pass the target index of the left child
        tree[j] = it.next().value; // Get the next input value and place it here
        inorderAssign(j*2 + 2); // Pass the target index of the right child
    }
    inorderAssign(0);
    return tree;
}

const nums = [4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];
const tree = createBinaryTree(nums);
console.log(...tree);
```

Comment: 467, 310, 883, 146, 718, 356, 504, 12, 943, 204, 80, 468, 868, 374, 126, 132, 527, 533, 819, 576 fails for  case @trincot

Comment: You need to sort the input first, like you have it in your question. Anyway, I added a sort call to the function.

Comment: why sorting is necessary @trincot ?

Comment: Because a BST is a sorted collection. If you don't sort the data first, then how will you know what the root of the tree will be, ...etc? I mean, it is possible, but you would need to rotate the tree while inserting values, so to make sure it gets the desired *complete*  shape, and not some other one. This leads to more code, without any benefit in efficiency.

Comment: tracking this recursion is difficult any resources or intuition behind it can you please explain@trincot

Comment: It is an [inorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_implementation) of the target BST. Every recursive call (except those that immediately execute `return`) represents following a downward edge in the BST: the first recursive call goes to the left child, and the second one to the right child. The algorithm uses the fact that if you visit BST nodes in inorder fashion, you will get the values in sorted order. So here we *place* those sorted values in inorder fashion into the desired tree shape